# hboehm garbage collector uninitialized value errors and leaks

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

I'm experimenting with the [hboehm garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), and for now just trying to run their [simple example](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/simple_example.html). The issue is that when I check the result with Valgrind, I get lots of "Use of uninitialized value" errors and, ironically, memory leaks.

Full project of a minimal example that reproduces the issue.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# This "outer" CMake file works as a dependency fetcher, and it consists almost exclusively of ExternalProject commands.
# The "inner" CMake file under project/ is a more traditional CMake file. It uses the find_* commands to locate
# dependencies without any knowledge or assumptions about where those dependencies live or how they got there.

include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    libatomic_ops
    URL http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gc_source/libatomic_ops-7.6.2.tar.gz
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND "" BUILD_COMMAND "" INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(libatomic_ops SOURCE_DIR)
set(libatomic_ops_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")

ExternalProject_Add(
    hboehm_gc
    URL http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gc_source/gc-7.6.4.tar.gz
    DEPENDS libatomic_ops
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE TRUE
    # hboehm_gc requires libatomic_ops be placed in a libatomic_ops subdirectory
    PATCH_COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy_directory "${libatomic_ops_SOURCE_DIR}" "<SOURCE_DIR>/libatomic_ops"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./configure "--prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>"
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(hboehm_gc INSTALL_DIR)
set(hboehm_gc_INSTALL_DIR "${INSTALL_DIR}")

# Now that we have our dependencies on disk to be found, it's safe to configure (run cmake on) the real project
ExternalProject_Add(
    main DEPENDS hboehm_gc
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/project"
    BUILD_ALWAYS TRUE
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${hboehm_gc_INSTALL_DIR}"
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND "${CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND}" --verbose
)
```

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

find_path(HBOEHM_GC_INSTALL_DIR include/gc.h)
find_program(VALGRIND_COMMAND valgrind)

add_executable(main src/main.cpp)
target_compile_features(main PRIVATE cxx_std_14)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE "${HBOEHM_GC_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libgc.a" pthread)
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE "${HBOEHM_GC_INSTALL_DIR}/include")

enable_testing()
add_test(NAME valgrind COMMAND "${VALGRIND_COMMAND}" "$<TARGET_FILE:main>")
set_tests_properties(
    valgrind PROPERTIES
    PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION "ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts"
)
```

---

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <gc.h>

int main() {
  int i;

  GC_INIT();    /* Optional on Linux/X86; see below.  */
  for (i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
   {
     int **p = (int **) GC_MALLOC(sizeof(int *));
     int *q = (int *) GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC(sizeof(int));
     assert(*p == 0);
     *p = (int *) GC_REALLOC(q, 2 * sizeof(int));
     if (i % 100000 == 0)
       std::cout << "Heap size = " << GC_get_heap_size() << "\n";
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Just need to:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It'll download hboehm_gc and dependencies, build the project, and run valgrind. I'm hoping I'm just misusing the library in some way, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice to explain why are your experimenting with GC and what kind of application using that GC do you have in mind...

Comment: Without a lot more context and motivation (which I did ask for) your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect Boehm's collector to have *some* memory leaks (because **it is a *conservative* GC**). Since Boehm GC is a conservative GC, it does not (and cannot) provide strong guarantees. But you hope that it won't have too much leak or memory waste (some papers mention a 20% leak rate as typical with Boehm's GC on Linux/x86-64). Boehm's GC has a page about [*Advantages and Disadvantages of Conservative Garbage Collection*](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/issues.html) that you should absolutely read. And there is also a [detailed description](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/gcdescr.html) of it, and finally it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can (and perhaps should) study its source code.

Both Boehm and valgrind use similar technology, so they cannot play well together. Obviously valgrind would detect a lot of memory leaks in any code using Boehm GC. Using valgrind on code linking Boehm's GC is useless. You might clear explicitly every memory zone obtained with `GC_MALLOC`.

If you need a precise GC (in particular if you need more guarantees about GC), choose something else, or code your own one (a naive precise mark&sweep stop-the-world GC is easy to code, at least in a single-thread program; the boring part is to maintain the GC roots and give access to your local "variables" containing pointers. You'll put them in some `struct` in every call frame, and link these `struct`-s together). Maybe look into [Ravenbrook's MPS](https://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps/), or my old, unmaintained and buggy, [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/qishintro.html) (perhaps it could inspire you). Look also into [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) GC and how you should [interface C with Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html).

Read also the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/).

BTW, your question is surprising: valgrind (its [memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) tool) is for hunting missing `free`-s, and the whole point of Boehm GC is to render `free` "useless" by providing a `GC_MALLOC` (replacement of `malloc`) which does not need any kind of freeing operation (so there is no point on using valgrind on a program which do `GC_MALLOC`-s).

Comment: If Boehm and valgrind don't play well together, is there another way to know the leak rate and check other memory issues?

Comment: Probably not. You can only use Boehm's GC API. And if you use Boehm's GC, you accept that it is conservative and that you will have leaks. And I don't understand why you want to know the leak rate? Please edit your own question to explain more

Comment: Basically, if you want to measure the leak rate, you need to implement your own precise GC in addition of using Boehm, have your precise GC compute the cumulated size and number of live objects, and compare that to what Boehm's GC consume. It is worth the effort? Probably not ... (unless you are writing a paper to compare GCs)

Comment: Just for my own peace of mind. I like to be able to verify that things are working as expected. If I can't use valgrind, then I suppose I have to just assume, for the most part, that hboehm is working as advertised?

Comment: Boehm's GC advertises as a *conservative* GC. There is no promise of avoiding "leaks". It works heuristically, so sometimes *badly*. It looks like you are expecting too much from Boehm GC (which in practice works quite well most of the time). It cannot and does not provide guarantees!

Comment: I still don't understand what kind of application do you have in mind. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52251699/edit) your question to improve it? What would happen if 30% of the memory is "lost"? In many cases, you should not care. But I cannot read in your mind and guess what application you are coding

Comment: My question as-is asked what I wanted to ask. I wanted to know why valgrind reported errors, and the answer it seems is, "Boehm and valgrind don't play well together." All my comments after that were follow-up discussion.